# Solaris T5120 How to reset firmware root password

Tags: root, solaris, firmware, reset

I have this Solaris T5120 box bought used no HDD so there is no OS yet

I was able to connect using Serial Console using HyperTerminal

Default User/Password didn't work

1. root changeme

[image: root changeme]

2. sunservice changeme

[image: sunservice changeme]

[image: root changeme]

I see 3 pins on this and i have tried putting jumper on both side so either 1 and 2 or 2 & 3

Red Jumper is on top right corner

[image: Jumper Location]

### What I have tried

I tried following http://bluepilltech.blogspot.com/2015/02/infodoc-209731-how-to-reset-ilom-on-sun.html and placed jumper power it on but still root changeme and sunservice changeme doesn't work

I tried xyzzy it got me to a prompt once but then "eeprom security-mode=none" kept saying unknown command

[image: u-boot command]

Comment: I think you can either use the reset jumper or use the "xyzzy" hack (enter "xyzzy" during the two second startup time) to get to the U-boot prompt and use `eeprom security-mode=none`.

Comment: Also, the default is "sunservice" and "changeme", not "root".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wasn't easy

I spent 2 hours because of vague and bad instructions

1. Add Jumper to 1 and 2
2. at the login prompt user : default
3. It said "Press and release the physical presence button.
   Press return when this is completed..."
4. Clicked the white button on the front panel which makes the lights go on and off
5. Went back to terminal and Hit Enter
6. Type password defaultpassword
7. I am in
8. To reset type "set /SP/users/root password+ " - Hit Enter
9. Type your new password

Comment: Thanks! I have 2 T5120 machines. One made under Sun, another under Oracle. The one under Sun has black pins for the jumpers, the one under Oracle has white pins for the jumpers. The description above works for the T5120 with the Oracle logo. ... for the other system I have used root/changeme

Answer (score 1):

Let's have this as an answer.

So, I have 2 kind of T5120 machines.  One made under Sun, another under Oracle.

The one under Sun has black pins for the jumpers, the one under Oracle has white pins for the jumpers.

For the one with black pins, use root/changeme ... for the one with white pins use default and then the indicator button as describe in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

SeanClt answer above is correct. Some additional clarification

- Also works for Sparc Enterprise T5220 service processor password reset
- Physical presence button is the upper one, front panel with bulls eye logo
- Alternatively the rear one beside the power supply. Button is clear, not white.
- White jumpers are underneath the centre set of PCI cards [Jumper PJ6801](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0opV.jpg)
- Login is via terminal software (eg minicom) to serial cable to SER MGT port, 
  with settings 9600,8,N,1
- The login prompt is (SP hostname) login:
- After successful login with default/defaultpassword the prompt is ->
- You can't make a mistake then backspace entering the password
- You can retry several times without having to power cycle